# Using induction to prove that $nx^{n-1}(x-y)\ge x^n-y^n$ for $n>0$, $x>y>0$.

Tags: inequality, induction

Let $p(n)$ be that the statement $nx^{n-1}(x-y)\ge x^n-y^n$ is true for some $n$.

Base case: obviously follows.

Inductive step: assume $p(k)$ is true for some $k$.
Look at $$(k+1)x^{k-1+1}(x-y) = (kx^k+x^k)(x-y) = 
$$
$$
n(x)x^n - nyx^n+(x)x^n-yx^n > kx^{k+1}-kyx^k+x^{k+1}-yx^k > kx^{k+1}-kyx^k. $$

I'm stuck here.

I know there is a way to do it using the property $(x^n-y^n) = (x-y)$(some polynomial), but we were specifically asked not to use that and to do it by induction.

Answer (score 3):

$$(k+1)x^k(x-y)=kx^{k-1}x(x-y)+x^k(x-y)\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}\ge x(x^k-y^k)+x^{k+1}-x^ky=$$

$$=2x^{k+1}-xy^k-x^ky$$

Thus it suffices to show that

$$2x^{k+1}-xy^k-x^ky\ge x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}\iff x^{k+1}+y^k\left(y-x\right)-x^ky\ge 0\iff$$

$$\iff x^k(x-y)+y^k(y-x)\ge 0\iff (y^k-x^k)(y-x)\ge 0$$

and since the last inequality is obvious we're done.